# How to throw the crate in Inside on iOS?

Tags: ios, inside

In the end of *Inside*, after you

> transform into a big blob,

you need to throw a crate up several times to proceed.

On iOS, to interact with objects, you need to press and hold, that makes you take the crate.

Swiping up and holding allows you to put the crate on top of you.

However, after that, swiping up as for jumping makes you drop the crate on most tries. Sometimes the crate is indeed thrown, but this is very inconsistent.

Is there a way to throw the crate consistently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use multitouch.

Press and hold, then swipe up and hold with one finger to put the crate on top of you, then swipe up with another finger (while still holding with the first one) to throw.

This is not obvious, as you can easily play the entire game except this part with just one finger.

Comment: Note that this is a self-answer as encouraged by this site rules. I couldn’t find the answer on the web, and it took me quite some time to figure it out by myself, so I put it here for those who may be stuck on the same problem.